# Can't compile image after upgrading to OS X Yosemite

Tags: graphics, mac

I have MacTex installed in my mac. It works fine before I upgrading to OS X Yosemite. After the upgrade, I can still compile the textual part, but the image part gives me this error:
http://pastebin.com/0Bk6XraW

Mainly complain about `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib`?

Anybody has similar problem? How do you solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually, X11 is not erased but moved to /opt/X11.

So, the simplest solution would probably be to manually add the symbolic link from /usr/X11 to /opt/X11:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/X11 /usr/X11
```

Answer (score 4):

Fixed after installing the latest XQuartz: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

The problem seems to be related to the fact that X11 was erased during the upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem after installing OSX Catalina ...

But now, you need to make a link like this:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/X11 /private/var/select/X11
```

(The link `/usr/X11` points to `/private/var/select/X11` and can't be modified.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with another program that was working prior to upgrading to OS X Yosemite, and then returned the following error subsequent to upgrading:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/grosbj/LANL/MCNP5/bin/mcnp5
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

fabianfuchs' suggestion fixed it!:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/X11 /usr/X11
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome, this is more like a comment than a real answer to the question. Once you got enough reputation, you can leave comments yourself. Right now i think, your answer will be converted to a comment by a mod soon.